# from XML to JSON if property begins with XX

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

I have this function

```
request.execute('[someSP].[spSomeSP]', function(err, dataset) {
      _.map(dataset, function(items) {
        console.log(items);
      });
 });
```

where the `_.map(...)` returns:

```
  { BET: 57635034,
    CUSTOMER: 181645,
    SPORT: 'NFL',
    'XX_FILL OPEN': '<element>\r\n\t<element_type>wager_action_button</element_type>\t\r\n\t<element_name>Fill Open</element_name>\r\n\t<element_call>fillOpen(57635034)</element_call>\r\n\t<element_content></element_content>\r\n</element>',
    XX_VIEW: '<element>\r\n\t<element_type>betslip_selection_checkbox</element_type>\t\r\n\t<element_name></element_name>\r\n\t<element_call>addRemoveSelectionFromSlip_checkbox(1738756,0,1,1)</element_call>\r\n\t<element_content>0</element_content>\r\n</element>'}
```

as you can see, the properties starting with `XX_` have XML attributes, I want to convert those XML into JSON.

I have tried something like this but it logs `-1` and I don't know why.

```
      _.map(dataset, function(items) {
        console.log(items.indexOf('XX'));
      });
```

I need to do it with xml2js = `parseString = require('xml2js').parseString`

what are your recommendations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `indexOf` is called against the object (array). What you need is to call it against each property name which you have in your items:

```
_.map(dataset, function(items) {
  for (var item in items) {
    if (items.hasOwnProperty(item) && item.indexOf('XX') === 0) console.log(item, items[item]);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know why but it is not entering in the if :S

Comment: well, it should... Try to debug the conditions one-by-one

Comment: this is `false` `item.indexOf('XX') === 0` why ?

Comment: is it false for XX_VIEW? What is the string?

Comment: The info I post above its all I have so far.

Comment: yes but you say this is false but you don't say for which string it is false

Comment: just fix it, my bad. Thanks